# Find predecessors in a BinaryTree in O(1)

Tags: time-complexity, binary-tree

I've been having trouble with the following question

I have a given Binary Tree (not necessarily BST) and two pointers `(x,y)` and I need to find if X is Y's predecessor in a O(1) complexity, I can add as many fields as I want.

I was thinking about adding each predecessor as a field as I insert the next child to the tree but in that way how can I search if X is Y's predecessor in O(1) complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use nodes, add an unsigned int field, call it `L`, starting at 1 with root.

When you recursively insert, take the value of the previous node and multiply by 2 then add 1 if you go right, or simply multiply by 2 if you go left.

You will get a tree of `L` values that looks like this:

```
          1
         / \
        /   \ 
       /     \
      /       \
     10       11 
    /  \      / \
   /    \    /   \
 100   101 110   111
  \             /  \
 1001         1110  1111
   /
10010
```

An ancestor `P` should have a value `P.L` such that `P.L` is a substring of `C.L` and the number of bits in `P.L` is strictly less than the bits in `C.L`.

The tree's `L` values in base-10 is:

```
          1
         / \
        /   \ 
       /     \
      /       \
     2         3
    /  \      / \
   /    \    /   \
  4     5  6     7
  \             / \
   9          14   15
   /
  18
```

If you have both pointers, if you take `log_2(L)`, You will get the # of bits in that number `L`, which if you notice, represents the level in the tree you are at.

So if:

```
// Parent (ancestor) has equal or more bits?
if (log(P.L) >= log(C.L)) {

  // parent is not an ancestor because it
  // is either lower in tree, or at same level
}
```

If that check passes, Subtract `bits(P)` from `bits(C)`, this will tell you how many more bits C.L has than P.L. Or, how many levels `C` is lower than `P`.

```
int D = log(C.L) - log(P.L)
```

Since `C` is lower, and all we did to calculate `C.L` value was multiply parent' `L` values by two (shift left) some number of times, if we were to shift C back over to the right (divide by 2) `D` times, the first `D` bits should match.

```
// Divide by 2, D times 
int c = C.L >> D

// Is P.L a substring of C.L?
if (c == P.L) {

  // P.L is a substring of C.L
  // means P is an ancestor of C
}

// If we get here, C is below P in the tree, but C
// is not in a subtree of P because the first `D bits don't match`
```

In essence, we use integers as strings to keep track of the path of insertion, and we use bit manipulation to check if `C.L` is a substring of `P.L` in constant time.

Note, if you used an array, then `P.L` and `C.L` are simply the indexes of the nodes you would like to check.